# Selecting all images, including images dynamically added by jQuery then calling a function

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-selectors, bind, live

I am running an each function on all divs with a class video. During that each function I am appending  tags with images to the DOM.

I then want to check that all images are loaded using this plugin: https://gist.github.com/268257

However, the selector isn't selecting the images that were appended in the each function.

Any ideas on to how to select all images, included the ones added by the each function?

```
$('.video').each(function() {

//load in images using json and append them with an <img> tag

});

$('#posts .video').find('img').imagesLoaded(function(){

// do stuff after all images have loaded


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your second function, as the callback of the first function

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that? I've tried looking for how to do a callback for a .each function but am having no luck.

Comment: Where do you check the images are loaded. Can you send us the whole script? Your explanation is a little unclear :)